# RTSP Stream don't work with python script but just works fine over the terminal using gst or in VLC

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, gstreamer, rtsp

I'm trying to record a video stream from an IP camera in ROS using a python script. My ROS program is running in a docker container and deployed on linux 20.04. The video recorder is a reused python script that works just fine for month in user projects and HW but with the same camera.

Unfortunately, on my HW I don't manage it to work. I always get following errors when starting my container :

```
[INFO] [camera_driver-1]: process started with pid [27348]
[camera_driver-1] [rtsp @ 0x563fcf484e80] method SETUP failed: 501 Not Implemented
[camera_driver-1] libva info: VA-API version 1.14.0
[camera_driver-1] libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so
[camera_driver-1] libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_14
[camera_driver-1] libva error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so init failed
[camera_driver-1] libva info: va_openDriver() returns 1
[camera_driver-1] libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
[camera_driver-1] libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_10
[camera_driver-1] libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
[camera_driver-1] [ WARN:0] global ./modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (1063) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: unable to query duration of stream
[camera_driver-1] [ WARN:0] global ./modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (1100) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Cannot query video position: status=1, value=0, duration=-1
```

Thinking the issue is due to gstream I updated and installed all packages and plugins of gstream as well as opencv.

Thanks that,I manage to get the streaming working in the terminal. So if a execute

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.4.21:8554/h264 ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

a window pops up and I can see my camera stream with a little latency.

Nevertheless, I always get the same issue concerning opening and recording the stream from the python script.

I googled a lot to try to find what could cause this issue... As I am not and experimented linux user, I'm don't really know where and what to check because I don't know which libs and packages are involved in the streaming process...

I would be happy about every input or idea which could help me to circumscribe this issue or maybe to solve it.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Post your Script

Comment: x86_64-linux-gnu may not be correct for Jetson Orin NX being aarch64. Be sure sure you get the correct driver for your target arch. 
The opencv warnings are harmless, a live source has no duration, so no current position that could be computed.

Comment: Hello, many thanks for your advice. I running my script on a x86 Intel atom plattform. Thus it shouldn't cause my issue.